# HasTextFrame - No access to text of group objects

Tags: excel, vba

I have 20 workbooks and cannot update the text (title 1 amount 1...) of the following Group objects added on top of graphs and appearing on each sheet.

Text of Group objects to be updated

The error coming up is with the  'If .Item(1).HasTextFrame Then'  line apparently.
Can you provide me with the clue to this please?
Thank you for your time and consideration

```
Sub B Macro()
'
' B Macro
'
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim numShapes, numAutoShapes, i As Long

    For Each wks In Worksheets
        With wks.Shapes
            numShapes = .Count
            
            If numShapes > 1 Then

                numTextShapes = 0
                For i = 1 To numShapes
                    If .Item(1).HasTextFrame Then
                        content = .Item(1).TextFrame.Characters.Text
MsgBox "Text: " & sMsg
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            End With
    Next wks
    '
End Sub
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Tx for answering. The error 'Run-time error '438'. OBject doesn't support this property or method'. And clicking on 'debug' the following line of the code above is highlighted :  If .Item(1).HasTextFrame Then         And i suppose the following is not right either (content = .Item(1).TextFrame.Characters.Text)? Thanks in advance for your insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HasTextFrame` is a property of `ShapeRange` and not of `Shape`.  If you just want to check for text content you could do something like this:

```vb
Sub BMacro()

    Dim wks As Worksheet, numTextShapes As Long, shp As Shape
    Dim numShapes As Long, itm As Shape
    
    For Each wks In Worksheets
        numShapes = wks.Shapes.Count
        If numShapes > 1 Then
            numTextShapes = 0
            For Each shp In wks.Shapes
                If shp.Type <> msoGroup Then        'not a group?
                    Debug.Print ShapeText(shp)
                Else
                    For Each itm In shp.GroupItems  'loop grouped items
                        Debug.Print ShapeText(itm)
                    Next
                End If
            Next shp
        End If
    Next wks
End Sub

Function ShapeText(shp As Shape) As String
    If Not shp.HasChart Then   'ignore chartobjects
        On Error Resume Next   'ignore error if no textframe...
        ShapeText = shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Dear Tim, I highly appreciate you took the time to help me on this one :) A great way for me to learn in the process. The community is lucky to have you. Thanks again

Comment: To help anyone coming along later with a similar question, please flag as Accepted using the checkmark.